# GTK y-axis padded label doesn't vertically ALIGN_BOTTOM?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtk2

I'm trying to align a label so that there is space on top and not on the bottom. What I want is about 30 between label1 and label2 but not between label2 and label3. I set label2 y padding to 30 and then on label2 y Gtk::ALIGN_BOTTOM, but it doesn't seem to work. Instead what I end up with is what looks like in the screenshot to be 30 on the top and 30 on the bottom of label2. I know there are ways around this but I want to know what is wrong with this code? I can't figure it out. I tried changing the pack options but that didn't work.

Here is the [screenshot](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3338/capture2o.png) and here is the sample code:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    Gtk::Main kit( argc, argv );

    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size( 400, 400 );

    Gtk::Label label1( "This is the first label." );
    Gtk::Label label2( "This is the second label." );
    Gtk::Label label3( "This is the third label." );

    label2.set_padding( 0, 30 );
    label2.set_alignment( Gtk::ALIGN_RIGHT, Gtk::ALIGN_BOTTOM );

    Gtk::VBox vbox;
    vbox.pack_start( label1, false, false, 0 );
    vbox.pack_start( label2, false, false, 0 );
    vbox.pack_start( label3, false, false, 0 );

    window.add( vbox );
    window.show_all_children();

    Gtk::Main::run( window );

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @ptomato it's gtkmm 2.22 on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like this (untested):

```
Gtk::Alignment alignment( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
alignment.set_padding( 30, 0, 0, 0 );
alignment.add( label2 );
```

The problem is that `label.set_alignment()` doesn't align within the padding, only within leftover space allocated to the widget.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tested, approved. So there is nothing wrong with the code, I just can't do it without an alignment?

Comment: @test, I think you can also use the 'valign' property of the label widget to set its alignment.

Comment: @spiritwalker You could do it with the `margin-top` property (not `valign`) in GTK 3, but this question is specifically about GTK 2.22.